# Как с помощью JS сохранить файл с веб-страницы?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser

Прямой ссылки на файл в коде верстки нет. На каждое обращение к текущему URL сервер отдает разные файлы. Требуется сохранить текущий файл(картинка)

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://gist.github.com/liabru/11263260) первоисточник.

Если у вас уже есть содержимое файла, а не ссылка на него, то можем воспользоваться кодом первоисточника, предварительно изменив код для картинок (почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type))

```
var img = "Содержимое файла тут",
    blob = new Blob([img], { type: 'image/png' }),
    anchor = document.createElement('a');

anchor.download = "test.png";
anchor.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
anchor.dataset.downloadurl = ['image/png', anchor.download, anchor.href].join(':');
anchor.click();
```

Если же изначально у вас есть лишь ссылка на файл, то содержимое файла нужно будет сначала получить ([Клац](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).